# Distribute files by size across multiple threads to balance workload

Tags: java

I've been asked the following

```
There are X number of compressed files of different sizes in a single folder.
Where X is 1 to 250.
File size ranges from 1MB to 65MB. The compression ratio varies from 9 to 11.

There are Y number of parser threads. Where Y is between 1 to 8.

Write an application that distributes the files so each thread receives the same amount of data ( or as close as possible ).
Please follow all best coding practices and standards you are familiar with.

For example

If X is 5 and Y is 3 and the files are
File 1 is 1MB, File 2 is 2MB, File 3 is 3MB, File 4 = 4MB, File 5 = 5MB.

Uncompressed File 1,2,5 = compressed file * 9. Files 3,4 = compressed file * 10

Output
Thread <thread number> = Files <file number...> = <total size of all files uncompressed>
...
Data skew = ((max size - min size) / max size ) * 100
```

Am I right in thinking it's an impossible question to answer, it seems very vague. It seems to me that this is a very hard question to answer in 1 hr.

I think that the distribution is non trivial.

---

**EDIT**

All I know of the problem is what is stated above.

To me it seems an awfully vague question.

Comment: It sounds tough, but not impossible. It does sound like a bin packing problem, so I would expect the computation to grow exponentially. How are you told the data compression for each file? Are you having to determine that somehow, or are they giving you a list of file names, sizes, and their relative compression?

Comment: You could outline the things you would do, the classes you would use.

Comment: @CodeChimp thanks for the pointer on 'bin packing' - as stated I only know what is shown above.  I think it's an appallingly asked question. It's hard to understand if the compression is a red herring or to be factored in. What sort of compression do they have?

Comment: I posted an answer that may help you.  I assume this is some sort of homework assignment.  As for what type of compression, there are loads of ways to compress files.  RAR, ZIP, 7z, ACE, to name only a few.  This could even be some strange attempt at some custom copression algorith, I don't know.  They all have their own methods of compression, but all do practically the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

So, as per my comments, I believe this to be an instance of the traditional [Bin Packing Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem), except in this case you have a set number of bins (threads) known ahead of time and the bins can grow, which takes some of the computation off.  Think of it as having X number of boxes that you have to fill with Y number of items, but the boxes can get taller.

First, I think you need to calculate the uncompressed file sizes up front.  The uncompressed file sizes are like the "volume" in the bin packing problem.

Next, I think you sort the files based on uncompressed values.  This makes searching the list faster.

For actually sorting them out, treat the Threads as "bins" in the bin packing problem.  I think there are tons of ways you could do it, and one question I would have before I settled on a particular approach would be: Are you more concerned with using all the threads up first, but making them as close to each other size as possible, or are you more concerned with getting the resulting sizes as close as possible, you just can't use more than the alotted threads?

If the concern is using all the threads, I think my approach would look something like:

1. Starting with the largest files, fill up the bins such that they are the smallest possible.  Keep doing this until you cannot put any more into any bins without exceeding the largest bin (the one with the largest file in it)
2. Place the smallest item in the smallest bin. This is you new "water mark"
3. As with Step 1, keep placing the largest file in the largest bins that will accept it without going over the water mark.  Keep doing this until you either run out of files or you can't put any more in without exceeding.  If the former, your done, if the ladder, go back to step 2.

If the concern, rather, is matching sizes, then my approach would be somewhat different.

1. Put the largest item in the smallest bin.  This is your "water mark".  Set it aside
2. Grab the smallest bin.  This is your working current bin.
3. Find the next largest item that will fit in the bin you are working on without making it go over the "water mark".
4. Repeat #3 until you can't fill the current bin
5. Put the smallest file in the smallest bin.  This is your new "water mark"
6. Just to #2

The benefit here is that I think you will get a very even distribution, as you are always keeping the "bins" as close the each other's sizes as possible.  The problem is it concerns itself with the sizes of the bins more than using them all up.

Comment: Thank you @CodeChimp for taking the time, it wasn't homework it was actually a pre interview test for a **top** company. They actually wanted code to implement it yet there are so many unknowns. Why they just wouldn't want to use a thread-pool I don't know. Thanks.

Comment: Good luck on your interview.  Hope you got something from my posting.